# Sed command and deleting lines

Tags: sed

In a bash script, I'm trying to delete all contents between starting with AAA (inclusive), and right up to BBB (exclusive). So therefore everything from AAA through just before BBB, and BBB would still be outputted. I came up with the line below, but it incorrectly is removing BBB also. Appreciate any help.

```bash
sed -i '/AAA/,/BBB/d' file.txt
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it ... `sed '/AAA/,/BBB/{/BBB/!d}' file` ?

Comment: what do you mean it's a duplicate? i can't test right now unfortunately but you sure about the answer? thanks.

Comment: Related question on SO: [stackoverflow.com/questions/16633308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633308)

Comment: Could the lines containing `AAA` and `BBB` contain other stuff? Like `fooAAAbar` or `fooBBBbar`? Might be a good idea to provide some example input data.

Comment: the lines both start with AAA and BBB but have some characters after it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If `AAA` and `BBB` are at the beginning of a line

[Using sed to delete range of lines except the end pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633308/using-sed-to-delete-range-of-lines-except-the-end-pattern) has the answer to your question:

```
sed -i '/AAA/,/BBB/{/BBB/!d}' file.txt
```

**Example input:**

```
AAA remove1
remove2
BBB keep3
```

**Example output:**

```
BBB keep3
```

### If they can occur somewhere in the middle of a line

You could use a regular expression:

```bash
sed -izE 's/(.*?)AAA.*?(BBB.*)/\1\2/g' file.txt
```

Parantheses are grouping parts of the regular expression so we can refer to their content by `\1` (first capture group) and `\2` (second capture group) later. `.*` matches any character (`.`) 0 or more times (`*`). The following question mark makes the `*` "lazy" which ensures it matches the shortest string possible (for `AAA foo1 BBB AAA bar2 BBB` `AAA.*?BBB` would match `AAA foo1 BBB` rather than `AAA foo1 BBB AAA bar BBB`).

The `-z` parameter separates lines by a NUL character rather than a line break allowing the regular expression to handle multiple lines.

**Example input:**

```
keep1 AAA remove1
remove2
remove3 BBB keep3
```

**Example output:**

```
keep1 BBB keep3
```

Comment: no they're on different lines of the file, several lines apart

Comment: BBB starts a new line, and I want the lines to all be deleted from the line that starts with AAA through the line right before BBB

Comment: Is that going to work any better or different than the simple    sed '/AAA/,/BBB/{/BBB/!d}'      shown above?

Comment: @Matt I updated my answer according to your more detailed requirements.

Comment: the lines both start with AAA and BBB but have some characters after each (e.g. AAAbbb390-444444). There are no other instances of AAA or BBB in the file.   That mean the   sed -i '/AAA/,/BBB/{/BBB/!d}' file.txt   will work?

Comment: Yes, the simple version should do.